post request for token name from address
I want to get a token name from a smart contract address. I have come to a code using web3 module. It works nice, but I can not use web3 - the code will be used in the environment (BI service) that does not work with web3. So I need to change it to post request form. And I do not understand how to write parameters (payload in the code for request module). Could someone help?
The web3 code is:
from web3 import Web3
import json

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://rpc.ankr.com/eth'))

payload = [{"inputs": [], "name": "name", "outputs": [{"internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string"}],
        "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"},
       {"inputs": [], "name": "symbol", "outputs": [{"internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string"}],
        "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}]

address = Web3.to_checksum_address('0x3f1c1bfce3dc639a6bdf0e60210a94c1d97da231')


contract = web3.eth.contract(address, abi=payload)

t_name = contract.functions.name().call()


print(t_name)

And the request form:
import requests

url = 'https://rpc.ankr.com/eth'
address = '0x3f1c1bfce3dc639a6bdf0e60210a94c1d97da231'

payload = {}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)

print(response.json())

I have checked docs for api but all the suggestions are for web3
